# Typescript Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this Array

```
numbers1: any=[
               { lat: 43.477254, lng: -3.780953 },
               { lat: 43.472739, lng: -3.781039 },
               { lat: 43.472498, lng: -3.780164 },
               { lat: 43.472023, lng: -3.780363 }
              ];
```

I want to fill that array dynamically, and I got it in this way:

```
list:any[]=[];

polygon(event){
   this.list = [event.coords.lat, event.coords.lng];
   this.number.push(this.list);}
```

But how can I set the values using the structure of Array number1?

> { lat: value, lng: value },

I've tried it but I have not got it. And Sorry by the way, im new on this.

Comment: You can leverage Typescript's strengths better if you use more specific types than `any`. For example, for that array of lat/lng coordinates, you might create a simple `Coord` class with `lat` and `lng` properties, then declare `numbers` to have the type `Coord[]`.

Comment: What's the intent between `this.numbers`, `this.list`, and `this.number`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to `push` an object, instead of an array:

```
this.list = {
    lat: event.coords.lat,
    lng: event.coords.lng
};

this.number.push(this.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push an array rather then an object. And above you have an array named numbers1 and you are pushing in number. Use the correct one

Try this:

```
list:any={};

polygon(event)
{
   this.list = {lat: event.coords.lat, lng: event.coords.lng};
   this.number.push(this.list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code references 3 different arrays: `this.numbers1`, `this.list`, and `this.number`. It's not clear to me if that's intentional distinction, but it *seems* what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
// describe what the arrays contain
type Coord = { lat: number; lng: number; }

// define the array of those coords, initialize empty
numbers: Coord[] = [];

polygon(event){
   // push the next coord (this will be type-checked)
   this.numbers.push({ lat: event.coord.lat, lng: event.coord.lng });
}
```

Note that using a custom type `Coord` instead of `any` the compiler will guide you in what you are trying to do. For example this would be an error:

```
this.numbers.push([event.coord.lat, event.coord.lng]);
```

Compiles with error:

```
Error:
  Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Coord'.
    Property 'lat' is missing in type 'any[]'.
```